# jQuery function called over and over in MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to call an action method when an textbox gets focus to get a description of the model object that field is associated with from a database.

I have this jQuery function:

```
    function getDescription() {
        $('.hourInput').focus(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var url = '<%=Url.Action("GetDescription", "Timesheet") %>'
            $.get(url, { name: name }, function (data) {
                $('#description').val(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

And this simple test action method for now:

```
    public ActionResult GetDescription(string name)
    {
        return Content("Testing");
    }
```

It works fine as far as getting the test text, but the problem is if I set a breakpoint in the action method, I see that it gets called over and over, not just when i change focus in the text boxes...

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but could it be where you are switching to Visual Studio and the back to IE you are causing the focus event to be triggered again?

Comment: Try different browsers, the jquery page for `focus` states that "scripts that rely on event delegation with the focus event will not work consistently across browsers."  Also, try using `$('#hourInput')` where hourInput is the input tag's ID.  What is the browser being used and what ver of jQuery?

Comment: @Matthew: Well, I thought about that too, so I don't think it sounds stupid at all, and that may well be the answer I guess, but Visual Studio gets switched to automatically for the breakpoint, so how would I know if that is the problem or if there is in fact some loop I need to fix? Also, I wouldn't have thought switching programs would cause it to receive focus over and over, I thought you had to at least be switching focus within the same page...

Comment: @James: I can't use the id selector because there are actually several input fields with this class that each need to get their own Description when receiving focus...

Comment: @Matthew: I tried a little "trick" to find out whether the action method was being called over and over if I didn't have a breakpoint. I used a Random object and returned it as a string. And it didn't keep changing if I didn't change focus, but did change when I switched focus to another input. So that should confirm that the method isn't called over and over unless I have a breakpoint, right? If so, please turn your comment into an answer so I can give you credit! Pity though... In effect it means I'm losing the use of the debugger if I have a jQuery focus function...

Comment: Look at FireBug. It will tell you the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound stupid, but could it be where you are switching to Visual Studio and the back to IE you are causing the focus event to be triggered again?

The other thing to consider is that you should really cache the response if the field description doesn't change.  In fact, do you actually need this action at all, can't you write out the field description when you're first rendering the page?

Comment: No, the thing is, as I mentioned in my comment to James, I have a bunch of input fields with the class hourInput (one row for each task, and one column for each day of the week), and they all have their own descriptions. So the point is to be able to show the description and let the user change it for the input field the user has selected. Thanks.